# PHP inferred path referencing the php document itself

Tags: php

Basically, this error message says it all:

```
file_get_contents(./users.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\login.php
```

This error is thrown for this piece of code:

```
    $ru = file_get_contents("./users.txt");
```

The file I want to access is users.txt. PHP appears to be searching through itself for this file. I've tried lots of stuff, including using the absolute path, to no avail. It always searches for whatever I put in those brackets within itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`file_get_contents` takes a `string` argument for the filename.

Try changing `file_get_contents(./users.txt)`

to

`file_get_contents('./users.txt')`.

EDIT:

After discussion in the comments, also make sure to check that your file wasn't named incorrectly. ie, `users.txt.txt`.

Comment: It seems to be quirk of the error call; the actual code has quotations around it. For clarity I'll edit it in

Comment: Could be nothing, but when I was testing, my file was named "users.txt" which got turned into "users.txt.txt". Maybe check the file properties to see if something similar happened?

Comment: Also, I believe the error isn't saying it can't find the file in the php file, it's saying the error is located in the php file.

Comment: I can't believe I've spent multiple hours agonising over a problem that was just a file being misnamed. You were right, it was called users.txt.txt, thank you so much

Comment: Haha, happens to the best of us. Don't sweat it.